# Querying Google sheets from GAS with SQL and Filtered rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

From a GAS script I perform a query

```
    function testSQL() 
{
  const fileKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const sheetName="Sheet1";
  const formatType="csv";
  
  var queryA="SELECT * WHERE 1=1";
  var queryURLA = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + fileKey + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:' + formatType + '&headers=1&sheet=' + sheetName + '&tq=' + encodeURIComponent(queryA);

  Logger.log(queryURLA);

  var retA = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryURLA, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getContentText();
  var retAV = Utilities.parseCsv(retA,",");

  Logger.log(retAV);

  return retAV;
}
```

If the excel columns are filtered, the filtered content and not the overall one is queried.

Unfiltered sheet:

[image]

Query result:

```
8:16:45 PM  Info    [[Row 1, Row 2, Row 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

(Correct)

Using a Filter (Row 3 is filtered out)

[image]

Query result:

```
8:20:14 PM  Info    [[Row 1, Row 2, Row 3], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Wrong!
Row 3 should appear regardless the filter on the sheet.

This is a Mess, that means if I do a filter to check some data, another user will have umpredictable results.

Can anybody confirm this the only possible behaviour ? any lightweight workaround?

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this behavior with part of the script that you shared and it returns all the data even if it's filtered. Can you share more of the script to compare what is different?

Comment: Ok I copied exactly the function I run directly. Could it be a permission issue?

Comment: Hi. Do you control the source spreadsheet? If so, then what if you created a dynamic copy of the data on a second sheet (no filtering) and then then access the second sheet rather than the first sheet.

Comment: First of all can you confirm you were able to replicate the behaviour and you agree it is as per your knowledge normal? Creating a dynamic copy has two issues: 1. the real sheet is very big. 2. Data are concurrently created by several people so if by dyamic copy you mean that  Cell A1 Sheet2 has a formula like "=Sheet1!A1" and so on, I tried it but if I put a new row the new does not appear to be reflected in the Sheet2. In other words i am not aware of any robust way to do a dynamic copy of one sheet to another.

Comment: @FuCo I was able to reproduce the same behavior, I was trying to investigate why that happens but so far I haven't found anything. Regarding the previous comment, as a workaround maybe you can use `IMPORTRANGE` and that way even if the original data is filtered it will show all data in the other sheet so you can fetch that data instead.

Comment: So far so good. The "cache excel" appears to work as expected (no significant delay on update, no significant increase in query time). The only potential problem is the size of replicated data: I had to create an importrange for each column, and i fear the time it will not be enough.